# What's the most efficient way to archive the discussions in an entire Facebook group?

Tags: facebook

I can use the iMacros Firefox extension to repeatedly click the "show more" button, and then save the page as a full webpage in Firefox. The problem is - though - that all the discussions have to be expanded too (and some discussions - those with more than 100 replies - have to be expanded multiple times)